# How to push existing value pair to Array using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to push the $pair to existing array but dont works...
I already use merge array and dont work.

```
  $pair = array(
        'status'    => 1
  );

    $numberof = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($numberof > 0)
    {
        // output data of each row
 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $tem = $row['status']  = '1';


 $json = json_encode($tem);
```

This is the final result :

```
{"0":{"id":"7","nome":"dfsdfsdfsdff","email":"and@gmail.com"},"status":1}
```

I only want this to final result:

```
{"id":"7","nome":"dfsdfsdfsdff","email":"and@gmail.com","status":1}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete?

Comment: @TobiasXy i show the code i use for this process

Comment: the problem is that your `$row` could have more than one record

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest but i can do it with array_push another variable?

Comment: post the expected output for multiple records

Comment: I have already posted, is in the final result .... @RomanPerekhrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used array in while loop. please with this I hope you can get your answer

```
    $pair = array(
        'status'    => 1
  );

    $numberof = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($numberof > 0)
    {
        // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { // instead $row[] use only $row



  $row['status']  = '1';


 $json = json_encode($row);
```

Comment: This dont work, you already tested this code?? The result of this code is "1", not the same...

Comment: @nodejscodrd please try now

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

$tem=array();
$temp=array_merge($tem,$pair);

and then encode $temp

Comment: I think i am not getting context of your $result->fetch_assoc().
 please try as 
$tem=array();
$temp=array_merge($tem,$pair);

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... }` 
instead 
`while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$pair = array( 'status'    => 1);

$numberof = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($numberof > 0) { 
    while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $row['status']  = '1';
    } 
    $json = json_encode($row);
}
```